# Question on Kleinman-Bylander pseudopotentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, spherical-harmonics

When Kleinman-Bylander pseudopotentials are used the Hamiltonian operator is given by
$$\hat{H} = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2+V_{\textrm{local}}+\delta \hat{V}_{\textrm{NL}}$$
where
$$\hat{V}_{\textrm{NL}} = \sum_{lm}\frac{\vert\chi^{\textrm{PS}}_{lm}\rangle\langle{}\chi^{\textrm{PS}}_{lm}\vert}
{\langle{}\chi^{\textrm{PS}}_{lm}\vert
\psi^{\textrm{PS}}_{lm}\rangle}
$$
See [1]. What happens if we have two orbitals with same $l$ and $m$ but different principal quantum number?

[1] Richard M. Martin. Electronic Structure: Basic Theory and Practical Methods. Cambridge University Press (2004).